# How to remove rows with similar data to keep only highest value in a specific column (tsv file) with awk in bash?

Tags: csv, awk

I have a very large `.tsv` file (80 GB) that I need to edit. It is made up of 5 columns. The last column represent a score. Some positions have multiple "Score" entries and I need to keep only the row for each position with the highest value.

For example, this position have multiple entries for each combination:

```
1   861265  C   A   0.071
1   861265  C   A   0.148
1   861265  C   G   0.001
1   861265  C   G   0.108
1   861265  C   T   0
1   861265  C   T   0.216
2   193456  G   A   0.006
2   193456  G   A   0.094
2   193456  G   C   0.011
2   193456  G   C   0.152
2   193456  G   T   0.003
2   193456  G   T   0.056
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
1   861265  C   A   0.148
1   861265  C   G   0.108
1   861265  C   T   0.216
2   193456  G   A   0.094
2   193456  G   C   0.152
2   193456  G   T   0.056
```

Doing it in python/pandas is not possible as the file is too large or takes too long. Therefore, I am looking for a solution using `bash`; in particular `awk`.

Thif input file has been sorted with the following command:

```
sort -t$'\t' -k1 -n -o sorted_file original_file
```

The command would basically need to:

- compare the data from the first 4 columns in the `sorted_file`
- if all of those are the same, then only the row with the highest value on column 5 should be printed onto the output file`.
  I am not very familiar with `awk` syntax. I have seen relatively similar questions in other forums, but I was unable to adapt it to my particular case. I have tried to adapt one of those solutions to my case like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print; next} NR==2 {key=$2; next}$2 != key {print lastval; key = $2} {lastval = $0} END {print lastval}' sorted_files.tsv > filtered_file.tsv
```

However, the output file does not look like it should, at all.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Fravadona yes, the data is sorted on the first and second columns

Comment: Only sorted on the first two fields? So it is possible to have __line1__ `1   861265  C   A   0.071`, __line2__ `1   861265  C   G   0.001` and __line3__ `1   861265  C   A   0.148`?

Comment: @Fravadona I am not 100% sure, but I from the single positions that I looked at, the fourth column is sorted as well. For each entry on the second column, the third column has only one possible entry. Therefore, it does not need to be sorted for the third column

Comment: BTW, I don't see any real reason to exclude python, as long as you process the file line by line

Comment: @Fravadona I tried it and it took too long for this purpose

Comment: OK, but processing 80GB is bound to take some time unless your disks are really fast. As you're required to provide some code in SO questions, please add your python code to the question.

Comment: if the data is *not* already sorted by the first 4 columns then you either need to presort the file or plan around potential out-of-memory errors; in your file is every other line actually blank? (if not, please update the question to show the exact contents/format of the file); is the first column always a `1`? is the third column always a `C`?

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, but I've found ````bash```` significantly faster (like 10-20 min vs 2-4 hours at least)

Comment: @markp-fuso I added the command I used to sort the original file, and a second example position in the table. It is not always 1 on the first column. For each column 1 and 2 combination, column 3 always have the same string value

Comment: @markp-fuso around 400'000 entries have ````1```` on the first column

Comment: does the ordering of the rows need to be maintained in the output? what version of `awk` are you using (`awk --version`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, they should retain the same order. Otherwise, I would need to do it again. (I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) with the command ````awk -W version```` I get: ````mawk 1.3.4 20200120````

Comment: Change `sort -t$'\t' -k1 -n`  to just `sort` with no options and it'll output the necessary order.

Comment: for last field you need to specify `-n` since `"2" > "12"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach. This also works on a non-sorted last column, only the first 4 columns have to be sorted.

```
% awk 'NR>1&&str!=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4{print line; m=0}
       $5>=m{m=$5; line=$0}
       {str=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4} END{print line}' file
1   861265  C   A   0.148
1   861265  C   G   0.108
1   861265  C   T   0.216
2   193456  G   A   0.094
2   193456  G   C   0.152
2   193456  G   T   0.056
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
1   861265  C   A   0.071
1   861265  C   A   0.148
1   861265  C   G   0.001
1   861265  C   G   0.108
1   861265  C   T   0
1   861265  C   T   0.216
2   193456  G   A   0.006
2   193456  G   A   0.094
2   193456  G   C   0.011
2   193456  G   C   0.152
2   193456  G   T   0.003
2   193456  G   T   0.056
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract from the `sort` manual:

> -k, --key=**KEYDEF**
>
> **KEYDEF** is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]` for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and **the stop position defaults to the line's end**.

It means that by using `sort -t$'\t' -k1 -n` like you did, **all the fields of the file have contributed to the numerical sorting**.

---

Here's probably the **fastest** `awk` solution that makes use of the numerical sorting in ascending order:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = "\t"
        if (getline > 0) {
            prev_key = $1 FS $4
            prev_line = $0
        }
    }
    {
        curr_key = $1 FS $4
        if (curr_key != prev_key) {
            print prev_line
            prev_key = curr_key
        }
        prev_line = $0
    }
    END {
        if (prev_key) print prev_line
    }
' file.tsv
```

**remark:** As you're handling a file that has around 4 billions of lines, I tried to keep the number of operations to a minimum. For example:

- **Saving 80 billions** operations just by setting `FS` to `"\t"`. Indeed, why would you allow `awk` to compare each character of the file with `" "` when you're dealing with a TSV?
- **Saving 4 billions** comparisons by processing the first line with `getline` in the `BEGIN` block. Some people might say that it's safer/better/cleaner to use `(NR == 1)` and/or `(NR > 1)`, but that would mean doing 2 comparisons per input line instead of 0.

<sub>It may be worth to compare the execution time of this code with @EdMorton's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655404/3387716) that uses the same algorithm without those optimisations. The disk speed will probably flatten the difference though ^^</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- file is sorted by the first field
- no guarantee on the ordering of fields #2, #3 and #4
- must maintain the current row ordering (this would seem to rule out (re)sorting the file as we could lose the current row ordering)
- the complete set of output rows for a given `group` will fit into memory (aka the `awk` arrays)

General plan:

- we'll call field #1 the `group` field; all rows with the same value in field #1 are considered part of the same `group`
- for a given `group` we keep track of all output rows via the `awk` array `arr[]` (index will be a combo of fields #2, #3, #4)
- we also keep track of the incoming row order via the `awk` array `order[]`
- update `arr[]` if we see a value in field #5 that's higher than the previous value
- when `group` changes flush the current contents of the `arr[]` index to stdout

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function flush() {                     # function to flush current group to stdout
    for (i=1; i<=seq; i++)
        print group,order[i],arr[order[i]]

    delete arr                         # reset arrays
    delete order
    seq=0                              # reset index for order[] array
}

BEGIN      { FS=OFS="\t" }

$1!=group  { flush()
             group=$1
           }

           { key=$2 OFS $3 OFS $4

             if ( key in arr && $5 <= arr[key] )
                next
             if ( ! (key in arr) )
                order[++seq]=key
             arr[key]=$5
           }

END   { flush() }                      # flush last group to stdout
' input.dat
```

This generates:

```
1       861265  C       A       0.148
1       861265  C       G       0.108
1       861265  C       T       0.216
2       193456  G       A       0.094
2       193456  G       C       0.152
2       193456  G       T       0.056
```

Answer (score 2):

a more robust way is to sort the last field numerically and let `awk` pick the first value. If your fields don't have spaces, no need to specify the delimiter.

```
$ sort -k1n k5,5nr original_file | awk '!a[$1,$2,$3,$4]++' > max_value_file
```

As @Fravadona commented, since this stores the keys, if there are many unique records it will have large memory footprint. One alterative is delegating to `uniq` to pick the first record over repeated entries.

```
$ sort -k1n k5,5nr original_file |
  awk '{print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}'   |
  uniq -f1                       |
  awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$1}'
```

we change the order of the fields to skip the value for comparison and then change back afterwards. This won't have any memory footprint (aside from `sort`, which will be managed).

If you're not a purist, this should work the same as the previous one

```
$ sort -k1n k5,5nr original_file | rev | uniq -f1 | rev
```

Comment: As I understand it, the desired output is only 1 letter from col $4 that is the max for that group. This does not produce that result. You need to add `-k4,4` to the sort (and then it will be the same as I did an hour before ;-)

Comment: k4 should be implied in k1, but not tested.  Also the spec says all 4 fields "...compare the data from the first 4 columns", not just 1 and 4.  In essence, the same as yours but you're not following the idioms.

Comment: *k4 should be implied in k1* Problem is that it has to go through k2 and k3 involve k4, no? And k4 is not a numeric comparison.

Comment: that's right, but you only need numeric sorting on the last field. The rest will be grouped regardless numeric or string.

Comment: You got my vote. This is the right way to do it. ;-)

Comment: I hope OP has at least 32GB of RAM for this to work

Comment: @Fravadona, right. I added an alternative version without memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

It's not awk, but using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), is very easy and interesting

```
mlr --tsv -N sort -f 1,2,3,4 -n 5 then top -f 5  -g 1,2,3,4 -a input.tsv >output.tsv
```

You will have

```
1       861265  C       A       1       0.148
1       861265  C       G       1       0.108
1       861265  C       T       1       0.216
2       193456  G       A       1       0.094
2       193456  G       C       1       0.152
2       193456  G       T       1       0.056
```

Comment: Thanks, a tool that I didn't know of. It should be reasonably fast (written in GO) and provides binaries for win/mac/freebsd/linux.

Comment: @Fravadona try it, it's a great tool, very well documented https://miller.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your real input is sorted by key then ascending value the same way as your example is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }
key != prevKey {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print prevRec
    }
    prevKey = key
}
{ prevRec = $0 }
END {
    print prevRec
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       861265  C       A       0.148
1       861265  C       G       0.108
1       861265  C       T       0.216
2       193456  G       A       0.094
2       193456  G       C       0.152
2       193456  G       T       0.056
```

if your data isn't already sorted then just sort it with:

```
sort file | awk ..
```

That way only `sort` has to handle the whole file at once and it's designed to do so by using demand paging, etc. and so is far less likely to run out of memory than if you read the whole file into awk or python or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

With sort and awk:

```
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1n -k4,4 -k5,5rn file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} !seen[$1,$4]++'
```

Prints:

```
1   861265  C   A   0.148
1   861265  C   G   0.108
1   861265  C   T   0.216
2   193456  G   A   0.094
2   193456  G   C   0.152
2   193456  G   T   0.056
```

This assumes the 'group' is defined as column 1.

Works by grouping first by column 1, then by column 4 (each letter) then reverse numeric sort on column 5.

The awk then prints the first group, letter seen which will be the max based on the sort.